# Typing a class member that gets overriden by a property in subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-typing

Here is an example code of what I have:

```py
class A:
  value: int
  
  def __init__(self, value):
     self.value = value


class B(A):
  @property
  def value(self) -> int:
     return 3
```

Dynamically this works perfectly, but pyright complains that `Type "property" cannot be assigned to type "int"`

Is there a way to type this properly? I want to be able to set the value in methods of other subclasses of `A`.

More precisely, I am looking for a way to express that accessing `a.value` (when `insinstance(a, A)`) should always yield an `int`, but that the implementation **may or may not** be a `property`.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot really reproduce, `pyright` doesn't complain, although `mypy` does, but it complains with "Cannot override writeable attribute with read-only property" but *that* should be fixable by providing a setter in your property

Answer (score 0):

Pyright is correct to complain - `value` type in `A` is different than in `B`, which breaks LSP. To type a property without implementing it, you can do this:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

class A(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def value(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplemented
```

Comment: `@abstractproperty` has been deprecated [since 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty). Instead, use `@property` `@abstractmethod`.

Comment: @InSync corrected, although it would be nice if Python issued a warning when using feature that has been deprecated for 10 versions.

Comment: I know that `Pyright` is right to complain. I want a way to type that accessing `a.value` should always yield an `int`, but that the implementation may or may not be a property. I will make that clearer in the question

Comment: Also I am not looking to make `A` an abstract class. In the example, `A` should be instantiable, (otherwise the purpose is defeated)

Comment: "value type in A is different than in B" it isn't.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is. Types of `value` on instances are the same, but on class level`B.value` is of type `property`.

Comment: @matszwecja but `value: int` is telling you the type of `some_instance_of_B.value`, which is `int` in both cases. Indeed, this passes pyright, and mypy complains, but only because you don't define a setter, the issue isn't that it's a controlled by a property